# Listening to Video Ad. Finish Event in Interstitial Ad (Google AdMob)

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have an interstitial ad-id with video types only.
Is it possible to listen whether the video play-back is completed to decide on some rewards for the user?

So far, AdListener has only loaded, failed, opened, left-app & closed events as described in [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/ad-events), but I need the video-play completion event.

**One alternate solution**(?) **to me:**
If the video length can be approximated / found, I can run some timer to detect the completion using the ad-closed event, but is it again possible to get the video duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rewarded interstitial ads https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6373180?hl=en

or on AdClosed event award with in-app goodies

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        //AdClosed now reward user with points etc
    }
});
```

Comment: I've known about **Rewarded-Interstitial** just after posting this question & it's the correct solution for me. 

Btw, `onAdClosed` method doesn't serve my purpose alone, cause I don't want to give the reward if the ad was not timed-out rather have been closed by the user.